# Avoid multiple db calls to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a list of n records and for each record id, I need to fetch a list of  integers (partids) from the database.

Currently from the app, I have to loop n times passing the main id to fetch each list from db.

Obviously this is affecting the performance of the app (.NET Winforms app using vb.net).

Is there any way that I can avoid multiple calls?

Like can I send a list of ids n get my desired result as output?

Example

- input : record1 having id 100
- output: id 100, partid 1, 2, 3

Same for n rows

I don't know how.. any help please

Comment: Please explain along with sample data instead of words

Comment: Include `partid`s into main query as `xml` field. It may or may not improve performance but reduce the number of requests.

Comment: I'm surprised. I believe VB can accept whole dataset at once and to not fetch SQL for every row.

Answer (score 0):

If you share your query your using we'll be able to give you feedback. Assuming however you have a query like

```
SELECT PartId FROM tblParts WHERE CategoryId = 100
```

You can use

```
SELECT CategoryId, PartId FROM tblParts WHERE CategoryId in (100,101,102 etc)
```

to query the database and return the relevant records all at once. (or even omit the WHERE clause to return everything in the table).

Then in the local datatable that you get back you can use the method `.Select("CategoryId=101")` to execute a local query against your data and then process your data as normal.